# How to append a callback function in the DOM using wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom, append

[image]I have been having an issue making call back function to display on the HTML DOM. The idea is to get the ID of the funds, then use the IDs to get the Fund prices and View history. What I have been getting is undefined

The view history is supposed to take users to where they see the history of fund prices in a paginated table.

For the view history page the idea is to pass the id into the url and get the idea and query the endpoints page on the id passed into the url. but the view history requires fund id, start date and end date
https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/swagger/ui/index#!/Prices/Prices_GetFundPriceByDateRange

I will really appreciate a help
thanks

````
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(resp) {
              for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
              //  console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));
             //${resp.result[i].FUND_ID} ${resp.result[i].FUND_NAME}
             //callbackfun(resp.result[i].FUND_ID)
                callbackfun(resp.result[i].FUND_ID);
                $('#pensionfund').append(
                   `<div col-md-3>
                       <h5>Price ${i+1}</h5>
                       <a id='#price${i+1}'>${resp.result[i].FUND_NAME}
                      <hr>
                       <p id="priceplace">${callbackfun(resp.result[i].FUND_ID)}</p>
                       <hr>
                       <a target="_blank" href="https://p/view-history/${i+1}" rel="noopener noreferrer">View History</a>
                      </p>
                    </div>`
                );
              }
            },

            error: function(xhr, status, error){
               var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
               alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            }
    });

    });

     function callbackfun(resp)
     {
        jQuery.ajax({  
                type: 'GET',

                url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetCurrentFundPrice?fundId=' + resp ,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(resp) {
                  console.log("This the result: ",resp);


                 for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
                  //console.log("This is the innerLoop", resp.result[i].UnitPrice)
                    $('#priceplace').append(`<h5> ${resp.result[i].UnitPrice}</h5>`);

                     //document.getElementById('unitprice').innerText = resp.result[i].UnitPrice;

              }
              },
              });
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below code i have assign values for each div to `append_data` under for loop and then add that data to `<div id="pensionfund"></div>` using `.html()` . Also , i have assign unique `id` to all div where `unit-price` will get display because we cannot have many id with `same name`. Working example :

```js
// find elements
var append_data = "";
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(resp) {
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
        callbackfun(resp.result[i].FUND_ID)
   //append data to variable
        append_data += "<div col-md-3> <h5>Price '" + i + 1 + "'</h5<p id='#price'" + i + 1 + "'>" + resp.result[i].FUND_NAME + "<hr><p id='priceplace_" + resp.result[i].FUND_ID + "' onclick='callbackfun(" + resp.result[i].FUND_ID + ")'></p><hr><a target='_blank' href='https://p/view-history/" + i + 1 + "' rel='noopener noreferrer'>View History</a></p></div>";


        //console.log(resp.result[i].FUND_ID);
      }
      //put data in div with id pensionfund
      $("#pensionfund").html(append_data);
    },


    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
      alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
    }
  });

});

function callbackfun(resp1) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',

    url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetCurrentFundPrice?fundId=' + resp1,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(resp) {
//assign price to particular id i.e :priceplace_1,priceplace_11 etc
      $('#priceplace_' + resp1).html("<h5> UNIT PRICE : " + resp.result.UnitPrice + "</h5>");



    },
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pensionfund"></div>
```